# App is paused by alert - can i stop this from happening?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uialertview

I was testing my app last night, which involves staying on all night. Unfortunately, the app was suspended when the device received an alert (it was about a provisioning profile expiring soon - but it could've been 10/5% battery, iCloud backup problems or anything else they have set as an alert).

Is there any way I can stop alerts from suspending my app, so it can continue to work as normal?

Comment: Isn't an iPhone app expected to be suspended (i.e. when the user receives a phone call)?  If your app breaks because of suspension, then it won't be much fun for the user.

Comment: You're right, it won't be. That's why I'm seeing if there's any way around that. The purpose of my app requires it be left on during the night, and so the user isn't available to get rid of the alert and have it continue. It's like any app where the user isn't around to get rid of alerts (e.g. wake up alarm, webcam)

Answer (score 2):

no. alerts are modal ... the ui is blocked by an alert

you COULD modify it for your process
for system alerts (that arent yours) you cant change that at all